# AngularJS - which watcher is dirty?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to understand why does $digest is constantly running (recursive loop) in my angular application.

I am trying to see which of the watchers are dirty.
Any ideas on how to do that?

The digest cycle is running constantly because the digest cycle runs watcher A, watcher A executes `B = new value`, then the next cycle B executes `A = new value`, etc.. In this example, A can be equal to B.

I am trying to find A and B, and stop them from happening.

Comment: You have a potential [X/Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. It might be easier for me to help you fix the problem that's causing the infinite $digest loop than the debugging logic you've written.

Comment: @glcheetham Thanks, I believe my edit is a better question

Comment: I agree about XY problem. At least provide basic outline of what your code does. Your request is about as generic as *"my car is running poorly"*